# LDAP changing user password on Active Directory

Tags: android, active-directory, passwords, unboundid-ldap-sdk

I state that I am a complete beginner to LDAP.
I have to let a user change its own password through an Android device. User has NOT administrative privileges.
Using the [UnboudId LDAP SDK](http://www.unboundid.com/products/ldap-sdk) for Java I'm able to bind to server and get the user entry using this code:

```
final SocketFactory _socket_factory;
final SSLUtil _ssl_util = new SSLUtil(new TrustAllTrustManager());
try {               
  _socket_factory = _ssl_util.createSSLSocketFactory();             
}
catch (Exception e) {
  Log.e(LOG_TAG, "*** Unable to initialize ssl", e);
}

LDAPConnectionOptions _ldap_connection_options = new LDAPConnectionOptions();
_ldap_connection_options.setAutoReconnect(true);
_ldap_connection_options.setConnectTimeoutMillis(30000);
_ldap_connection_options.setFollowReferrals(false);
_ldap_connection_options.setMaxMessageSize(1024*1024);

LDAPConnection _ldap_connection = new LDAPConnection(_socket_factory, _ldap_connection_options, [host ip], 636, [username], [password]);

Filter _filter = Filter.create("(userPrincipalName=" + [username] + ")");
SearchRequest _search_request = new SearchRequest([base DN], SearchScope.SUB, _filter);
_search_request.setSizeLimit(1000);
_search_request.setTimeLimitSeconds(30);            

SearchResult _search_result = _connection.search(_search_request);
```

This works and I get 1 entry and all the relative attributes. Now my task is to change the password [password] with a new [new password].
My attempts:

```
PasswordModifyExtendedRequest _password_modify_request = new PasswordModifyExtendedRequest([found entry DN], [password], [new password]);
PasswordModifyExtendedResult _password_modify_result = (PasswordModifyExtendedResult)_ldap_connection.processExtendedOperation(_password_modify_request);
```

This doesn't work due to LDAPException

```
LDAPException(resultCode=2 (protocol error), errorMessage='0000203D: LdapErr: DSID-0C090C7D, comment: Unknown extended request OID, data 0, vece��', diagnosticMessage='0000203D: LdapErr: DSID-0C090C7D, comment: Unknown extended request OID, data 0, vece��')
```

Then I've tryed

```
final Modification _replace_modification = new Modification(ModificationType.REPLACE, "unicodePwd", _get_quoted_string_bytes([new password]));
LDAPResult _result = _connection.modify([found entry DN], _replace_modification);
```

This doesn't work due to LDAPException

```
LDAPException(resultCode=50 (insufficient access rights), errorMessage='00000005: SecErr: DSID-031A0F44, problem 4003 (INSUFF_ACCESS_RIGHTS), data 0)
```

Finally I've tryed

```
final Modification _delete_old_modification = new Modification(ModificationType.DELETE, "unicodePwd", _get_quoted_string_bytes([password]));
final Modification _add_new_modification = new Modification(ModificationType.ADD, "unicodePwd", _get_quoted_string_bytes([new password]));
final ArrayList<Modification> _modifications = new ArrayList<Modification>();
_modifications.add(_delete_old_modification);
_modifications.add(_add_new_modification);
LDAPResult _result = _connection.modify([found entry DN], _modifications);
```

This doesn't work due to LDAPException

```
LDAPException(resultCode=19 (constraint violation), errorMessage='00000005: AtrErr: DSID-03190F00, #1:0: 00000005: DSID-03190F00, problem 1005 (CONSTRAINT_ATT_TYPE), data 0, Att 9005a (unicodePwd)��', diagnosticMessage='00000005: AtrErr: DSID-03190F00, #1: 0: 00000005: DSID-03190F00, problem 1005 (CONSTRAINT_ATT_TYPE), data 0, Att 9005a (unicodePwd) ��')
```

And now i have no more ideas... Any help will be appreciated, thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
final Modification _delete_old_modification = new Modification(ModificationType.DELETE, "unicodePwd", ('"' + oldPassword + '"').getBytes("UTF-16LE"));
final Modification _add_new_modification = new Modification(ModificationType.ADD, "unicodePwd", ('"' + newPassword + '"').getBytes("UTF-16LE"));
```

Did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I was able to resolve CONSTRAINT_ATT_TYPE issue in password change.  I had set minimum password age as 4 days, so AD wasn’t allowing me to update the password. AD throws generic error CONSTRAINT_ATT_TYPE for all such violations.  After setting minimum password age as 0 (None), everything works fine. AD password history also gets updated.

Refer:
http://www.javaxt.com/Tutorials/Windows/How_to_Authenticate_Users_with_Active_Directory

Answer (score 0):

"Minimum password age" was the source of my problem CONSTRAINT_ATT_TYPE

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Instead, vote up the answers that you find helpful. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/29968868)

Comment: This looks like a "Thank you" post to [this other Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15117979/12695027)

Comment: @HamidYusifli Did you flag this post as part of the review? I'm confused why it's still here.