# LDAP password reset but i don't have the old password from Java application

Tags: java, ldap, opends

I want to add code that helps me to reset LDAP user password , but as I searched I must have the old password to reset the and add the new password .
    How could I reset the password without having the old one.

I looked into that link , but it ended with solution contains the usage of the old password 
[LDAP changing user password on Active Directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11178481/ldap-changing-user-password-on-active-directory)

```
final Modification _delete_old_modification = new Modification(ModificationType.DELETE, "unicodePwd", ('"' + oldPassword + '"').getBytes("UTF-16LE"));
final Modification _add_new_modification = new Modification(ModificationType.ADD, "unicodePwd", ('"' + newPassword + '"').getBytes("UTF-16LE"));
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get rid of the first line, and change the modification type in the second to REPLACE.